# Reverse Many-to-Many relation in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I create reverse field in Django REST framework for both many-to-many related objects serializers?

```
**Models**

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    max_attendee = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='events_tags')


** Serializers **

class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='tag-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'location', 'location_name', 'date', 'max_attendee', 'description', 'image', 'created_by', 'tags')

class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    events = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='event-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)
```

Because there is no `events` field in Tags model, I cannot display events related to tags. However, reverse performs great because Many-to-Many relation is set in Events model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the field's related name?

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    events_tags = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='event-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'events_tags',)
```

Comment: Yes but it gives error as "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256724/include-intermediary-through-model-in-responses-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
events = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='event-detail')
```

to this:

```
events_tags = serializers.RelatedField()
```