# DRF - Nested Serialization Of m2m fields with through model

Tags: python, django, m2m, django-rest-framework

I am using a m2m field with a through model in DRF. Everything is working fine, EXCEPT when I try to nest the membership serializer.

models.py

```
class SweepStakes(models.Model):                                                          
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)                                      

class Event(models.Model):                                                                       
    sweepstakes = models.ManyToManyField(SweepStakes, through='EventSweepStakesMembership')

class EventSweepStakesMembership(models.Model):                                  
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                   
    sweepstakes = models.ForeignKey(SweepStakes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class EventSweepStakesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                      
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sweepstakes.name')                     

    class Meta:                                                                     
        model = EventSweepStakesMembership                                          
        fields = ('name', 'enabled',)

class EventSerializer(BaseTenantSerializer):                                                                     
    sweepstakes = EventSweepStakesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)             

    class Meta:                                                                     
        model = Event                                                               
        fields = ('sweepstakes',)
```

At this point, if I hook the `EventSweepStakesMembership` model and the `EventSweepStakesSerializer` up to a view, I get back exactly what I expect, output like this:

```
{"name": "thingy", "enabled" true}
```

However, when I hook the `Event` model and `EventSerializer` serializer into a view, the `sweepstakes` field returns an empty dictionary instead of the nested representation, like so:

```
{"sweepstakes": [{}]}
```

Note that it is NOT an empty array, in other words it does see the related through model, but simply does not serialize it correctly when displaying.

There is no error, it is just empty. I have tried increasing the `depth` of the `Event` serializer to no avail.

Am I missing something or maybe even going about this all wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it, thanks to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17263583/1366989

The missing element here was the `source` kwarg on the `EventSerializer`. So, it now looks like this, and is working as expected:

```
class EventSerializer(BaseTenantSerializer):                                                                
    sweepstakes = EventSweepStakesSerializer(                                    
        source='eventsweepstakesmembership_set', many=True, read_only=True       
    )
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. You quite possibly saved me a couple of hours which otherwise would have been spent digging into DRF source..