# The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `GenericRelatedObjectManager` instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I can't figure out why I'm getting this  error "The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `GenericRelatedObjectManager` instance. Original exception text was: 'GenericRelatedObjectManager' object has no attribute 'country'.".  I been working on this for days, Can someone help me please? What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

I want to create a nested serializer that has a CRUD functionality. Planning to use this in my DRF.

I have 3 interrelated models namely Company, Address, and Country.

- Company model have a field called "**address**" and it's a GenericForeignKey.
- Address model have a field called "**country**" and it's ForeignKey.
- Country model is a CountryField(). I'm using django_countries plugin.

**Model Structure**

```
Company
 |__Address (GenericForeignKey)
    |___Country (ForeignKey)
```

**Company Model**

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class SalesClientCompany(models.Model):
            address = GenericRelation(
                Address,
                null=True,
                blank=True,
            )
```

**Address Model**

```
class Address(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    object_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=False,
        unique=False,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        verbose_name=_("Country"),
        to_field='country',
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

**Country Model**

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Country(SmardtAbstractHistory):

    country = CountryField(
        unique=True,
    )

    name = SmardtTranslateField(
        models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            null=True,
        )
    )
```

**Serializers**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType, ContentTypeManager


from models.client_companies import SalesClientCompany
from country.models.countries import Country
from models.addresses import Address


class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('country',)


class ClientCompanyAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountrySerializer()
    # country = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), slug_field='country') 
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('line_first', 'line_second', 'province', 'country',  'postal_code',)



class ClientCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    address = ClientCompanyAddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = SalesClientCompany
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'address',  'email', 'phone', 'type', 'company_directory']

    def create(self, validated_data):

        company = SalesClientCompany(
            name=validated_data['name'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            .....
        )
        company.save()

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(SalesClientCompany)

        company_address = Address(
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=company.pk,
            content_object=company,
            country=validated_data['address']['country'],
            .....

        )

        company_address.save()

        return company
```

**Inspect Serializer**

```
ClientCompanyAddressSerializer():
    line_first = CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Address Line 1', max_length=255, required=False)
    line_second = CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Address Line 2', max_length=255, required=False)
    province = CharField(allow_blank=True, label='State/Province/Region', max_length=255, required=False)
    country = SlugRelatedField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), slug_field='country')    
    postal_code = CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Zip/Postal Code', max_length=255, required=False)
```

**View**

```
class ClientCompanyCreate( generics.ListCreateAPIView ):
    queryset = SalesClientCompany.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientCompanySerializer
```

Answer (score 10):

Even though your serializers are aware of each other, the serializers don't know how to link the models together.  You need to specify the `source` parameter when initialising the [nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects), and provide the value of the `related_name` of the foreign key in the model.

For example:

```
class ClientCompanyAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountrySerializer(source='country_set')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('line_first', 'line_second', 'province', 'country',  'postal_code',)
```

In your code, you did not provide an explicit `related_name` when defining your `ForeignKey` field, so Django [automatically generated related name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/171993) `country_set` (model name + '_set').

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51202615/171993) ("*Django Rest Framework Nested Serializers*") and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17263583) ("*Include intermediary (through model) in responses in Django Rest Framework*").

Comment: I am facing the same issue but when I `serializer` with `product` = Model.objects.get(id=1)` it's work perfectly but when using `queryset = Model.objects.all()` it's start throwing above `Error`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't post in comments but won't the field in serializer class will be tuple.

```
fields = ('line_first', 'line_second', 'province', 'country',  'postal_code',)
```

Comment: `('a','b','c')` test

Comment: ClientCompanyAddressSerializer class contains fields which is not in address model

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get what you just said. Can you explain further?

Comment: Please ignore the fields. I have the complete field list in place.

Comment: list also works, i also tried changing  to tuple but it has the same result.

Comment: Sorry I am no expert but have you tried country = CountrySerializer(many=True)

Comment: No worries, i appreciate your help. Yes, i did, but it didn't work. Maybe the basic implementation is not suitable for this because of the complexity of data structure.