# Serializing Many To Many intermediate table in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I would like to learn how to get many to many intermediate table's serializer data by whole `model` , not only by id.

```
#this is my model class
class ProductMaterial(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    material_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)



#serializer
class ProductMaterialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = ProductMaterial
           fields = '__all__'
```

This returns:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "material_rate": 0.3,
        "material_price": 6.7,
        "product": 186,
        "material": 7
    },
   {
        "id": 2,
        "material_rate": 0.7,
        "material_price": 1.7,
        "product": 186,
        "material": 8
    },
```

## Problems:

1. First problem is it duplicates data because of many to many table
2. I want to see my `product` and `material` model fields too.

## My target:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "product": {
                 "name" : "abcd",
                 "date" : "01.01.2018"

                },
    "material": [
                  {
                     "id" : 7,
                     "material_rate" : 0.3,
                     "material_price" : 6.7,

                  },
                  {
                     "id" : 8,
                     "material_rate" : 0.7,
                     "material_price" : 1.7,

                  },
               ]
},
```

## Solution 2:

I have implemented this solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834689/5491260
and it helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the doc,

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the
>   depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a
>   flat representation.

So, use [**`depth=1`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in Meta class

```
class ProductMaterialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = ProductMaterial
           fields = '__all__'
           depth = 1
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my 2. problem. Could you share with me how can i solve "duplication" problem ?

Comment: What is the duplicate data here? **`product`**?

Comment: yes **product** duplicates. As you see on my target I want to get like that format.

Comment: In my model **a** `Product` can have **many** `Material`s and **a** `Material` can be in **many** `Product`s and every `Material` has own `rate, price` in a specific `Product`, I'm expecting to get my data format like on **my target**

Comment: @JPG `Product` is a FK. I think `ProductMaterial` can only have at most 1 `Product` associated with it (not 1 or more).

Comment: @adnankaya As per the current model definition, you can't obtain the desired output (*Problem no. 2*). Because, that's how its behaves